# Flexible PCB design suggestion

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, altium, pcb-assembly

I'm currently learning to design a PCB. For this board, I want to sense the current in two different ways (using either analog or digital current sensors). Each sensor requires a current sense resistor with a different resistance value, and I want to keep my board flexible so I don't want to attach both resistors at the same time to the rest of the board, but instead design it in a way that I can choose which one to attach. As far as I know Variants can be considered, or maybe adding jumpers and manually connecting the current sensor that I want, but I'd like to know if there are any better suggestions from a more experienced point of view.

Comment: you want to put both sensors on the board? then just design a board with both sensors

Comment: yes I want to put both but not use both at the same time, for that I'm looking for a solution to be able to choose only one sensor to work with

Comment: So, do that? It seems like a circuit design question but not an Altium question. You can use jumpers so that your data connection is wired to one sensor or the other.

Comment: Resistors (including current sense) are inexpensive so unless you need to save every penny there doesn't really seem to be a compelling case for only putting one down. The design work for the flexibility would cost more than the resistor. Just design for both sensors and attach the desired one.

Comment: You can also consider using the same current sense resistor for both, and converting the measurement in software. E.g. resistor twice as big as it should be = meter reads twice what the current actually is, so just divide it by 2.

Comment: Jumpers in the middle of a sensitive current measurement is probably not a great idea. Jumpers in general is an open invitation to quality problems. Other than that, having several different BoM for the same PCB is common. It is usually also a great way to create logistics/spare part quality problems. What's best for any given scenario is a business decision based on production volumes. This isn't a call someone else can do for you.

Comment: As above a jumper would not be an ideal option. If you use milli ohm resistors a jumper may have contact resistance in that range, giving significant errors. Repeated connect cycles will likely see contact resistance changing each time. Consider placing both resistors in series then connect the appropriate sensor across each. If the total of two resistors is too high consider using one resistor as required by the first sensor, then another smaller resistor to make up the total required by the second sensor. The first sensor wires to the first resistor but the second sensor wires across both.